# Force autowire repository by name and not by type

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, autowired

I am trying to create a java + spring library (a seperate, reusable, application independent jar file) and use it in the application.
I show you a non-working example, that is already suitable to demonstrate my problem.

My problem is, that i have difficulties to autowire a repository by name and not by type.
The jar file logic is implemented here in one file called Library

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

public class Library {
    @MappedSuperclass
    public static class ChildEntity {
        public String childAttribute;
    }

    @MappedSuperclass
    public static class RootEntity<T extends ChildEntity> {
        public String rootAttribute;
        @OneToOne
        public T childEntity;
    }

    @Service
    public static class RootEntityService<T extends ChildEntity> {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(Library.REPOSITORY_BEAN_NAME)
        private RootRepository<T> repository;

        public RootEntity<T> findMyEntity() {
            return this.repository.findByChildEntity();
        }
    }

    @NoRepositoryBean
    public static interface RootRepository<T extends ChildEntity> extends Repository<T, Long> {
        public RootEntity<T> findByChildEntity();
    }

    public final static String REPOSITORY_BEAN_NAME = "entityRepository";
}
```

As you can see i have a RootEntity and a ChildEntity with a OneToOne relation.
The RootRepository is defined as @NoRepositoryBean, since Repository cannot have generic parameters.
The RootService is referencing for the RootRepository and i am trying to autowire by name and not type - using the @Qualifier annotation.

Here comes the application itself:

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.Library.ChildEntity;
import com.example.Library.RootEntity;
import com.example.Library.RootEntityService;
import com.example.Library.RootRepository;

public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Entity
    public static class RealChildEntity extends ChildEntity {
        public String realChildAttribute;
    }

    @Entity
    public static class RealRootEntity extends RootEntity<RealChildEntity> {
    }

    @Repository(Library.REPOSITORY_BEAN_NAME)
    public static interface RealRootRepository extends RootRepository<RealChildEntity> {
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication application;

        application = new SpringApplication(ApplicationConfig.class);
        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        application.run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private RootEntityService<RealChildEntity> rootEntityService;

    @Override
    public void run(final ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        this.rootEntityService.findMyEntity();
    }
}
```

The RealChildEntity has an application specific attribute.
I define the RealRootRepository to be a real repository, without generic parameters. I have also defined a bean name for this component to refer to.

I also have an ApplicationConfig class to define the service bean and the repo:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.example.Library.ChildEntity;
import com.example.Library.RootEntityService;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { Application.class })
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean(Library.REPOSITORY_BEAN_NAME)
    public <T extends ChildEntity> RootEntityService<T> entityService() {
        return new RootEntityService<T>();
    }
}
```

If i execute this application, than spring gives me the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in com.example.Library$RootEntityService required a bean of type 'com.example.Library$RootRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="entityRepository")
```

Spring tells me, that RootEntityService required a **bean of type**. Why by type?
I want a repository by name

What am i doing wrong?
How can i have a library service without extending it just because of the repository;

Thanks for your help in advance